# Regex domains with TLD when multiple subdomains

Tags: regex, subdomain

I have a long list of domains with subdomains that look like:

```
www.random.com
abc.api.random.co.uk
abc.def.api.random.ac.za
something.edu
another.random.net
random.pharmacy
```

There's between 0 and several subdomains on each entry (for example `abc.def.api.random.ac.za`). I'm trying to figure out how I can extract just the domain and the TLDs. For example, given the above output, I'm looking for:

```
random.com
random.co.uk
random.ac.za
something.edu
random.net
random.pharmacy
```

This goes a bit beyond my current understanding of regex. It seems we need to check:

- End of line is X characters preceeded by a dot (there are some TLDs longer than 3 characters, ie: `.pharmacy`)
- An optional group before that that is 2 characters: `co`, `ac` etc. (pretty sure none of the second-level domains in my list has more than 2 characters - [alternatively could build an explicit list of optional second-level domains to be more accurate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-level_domain))
- The string before that is the domain
- Anything before that is subdomain and we don't want it

Answer (score 0):

The regex you need is:

```
\w+(?:\.\w\w)?\.\w+$
```

were:

- `\w+` means one or more letter or digit
- `(?:\.\w\w)?` is an optional group that matches a period followed by two letters
- `\.\w+` matches a period and the remaining letters
- `$` is the end of the line

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GzCQ0D/1).

If you want to be less generic:

```
\w+(?:\.(?:co|ac))?\.\w+$
```

If you want to be even more precise, you need to specify the entire eTLDs (effective top-level domains) with periods:

```
\w+(?:\.(?:co\.uk|ac\.za)|\.\w+)$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GzCQ0D/2).

If you want to know all the effective top-level domains, there is a nice catalog by Mozilla Foundation named [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/).

Answer (score 0):

Just a little more food for thought.

You can do repeats using * (zero or more) and + (one or more), however you can also specify a range {x,y} (x or more, but not more than y).

This may be useful given that the second to last domain is very likely part of your tld if it is exactly 2 characters long.

You definitely want to use the $ (end of line) marker as horcrux points out, since you'll be working from the right side.

\w+.(\w{2}.)?\w+$

The (...)? means that anything in the capture group is optional. So it is looking for EXACTLY 2 letters followed by a decimal, as an optional middle entry.